# Does this code do anything?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this little bit of code in a project:

```
if ($(".c1 .c2").is(":hidden")){
    $(".c1").hide();
} else {
    $(".c1").show();
}
```

It seems quite tautological to me, since it semme to hide something if it hidden, or show it otehrwise. The only thing is the difference in selectors used, so there is some possible side effect. Changing it:

```
if ($(".c1").is(":hidden")){
    $(".c1").hide();
} else {
    $(".c1").show();
}
```

it would really do nothing, right?

Related HTML is as follow:

```
<span class="c1">
  <span>  </span>
  <span class="c2"> </span>
</span>
```

CSS as follow

```
.c1{ display: none; }
```

Comment: Note that the selector `.c1 .c2` has a different meaning than just `.c1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
if ($(".c1 .c2").is(":hidden")){
```

Is not checking if `.c1` is hidden, but is rather checking if `.c2` (which must be a descendant of `.c1` element, per the selector) is hidden.

Therefore it is essentially acting on the parent based on the status of the child.

Answer (score 2):

`$(".c1 .c2")` is not the same selector as `$(".c1")`. Also it is not hiding something that is already hidden, it is hiding a parent element with the class `c1` of something that is hidden. So changing it will probably break it. Also by changing it, the code no longer makes sense as now you are hiding something that is already hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding outer `.c1` if inner `.c2` is hidden? Why it *may* make sense.

Answer (score 1):

consider the following context:

```
<div class="c1">
    <h2>My very interesting list</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>
            Some
            <div class="c2">More information</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Other
            <div class="c2">More information</div>
        </li>
        <li>
            Data
            <div class="c2">More information</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If any of the descendant `c2` elements are hidden the entire block will be hidden. Which is very different from your latter example, which would in fact do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first code could be used to hide a parent container (`c1`), if the child (`c2`) is hidden. It does make sense if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

It probably does do something, but not in all cases.
It ensures that each .c1 is hidden if it contains a hidden .c2 and vice versa.

Ideally refactor to add more meaningful class names than c1 and c2

Answer (score -1):

Try using .toggle() like below

```
       $('.c1').toggle();
```